# Android: Access external storage directory and pass to JavaScript function in webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to pass a sound file which is recorded from the device and stored in device External Storage(not SD card)  to webview/javascript function.
But unable to get the actual path.

Implemented as below

```
    String filePath = "file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound001.wav";

 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test_fft.html");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String loc) {

                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:AudioFileRequest('"+filePath+"',0,5)");

                }
            });
```

**filepath** is giving **"file:///storage/emulated/0/sound001.wav"**

But my javascript function is not accepting the filepath soundfile.

Below is my javascript function

```
function AudioFileRequest(url,tBegin,tEnd, async) {
console.log(url);
console.log(tBegin);
console.log(tEnd+"haresh");
    window.tbegin=tBegin;
    window.tend=tEnd;
    this.tBegin=tBegin;
        this.tEnd=tEnd;
    this.url = url;
    if (typeof async == 'undefined' || async == null) {
        async = true;
    }
    this.async = async;
    var splitURL = url.split('.');
    this.extension = splitURL[splitURL.length - 1].toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Not getting any error, the javascript function is supposed to generate something that is not happening. error wise nothing showing when i inspect the webview in chrome.